# C# String ReadAllFile per lines

Tags: c#

I would like that when I press my button it opens an `OpenFileDialog` to load the content of a test file, e.g. proxys.txt.

I'd like all my proxys in my proxys.txt to be parsed as a string that I can use for a HttpWebRequest.

My code Form1:

```
OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFile1.Filter = "Load Proxys File |*.txt";

if (openFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(openFile1.FileName);
    string fileName = openFile1.FileName;
    string[] TEST = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    MessageBox.Show(TEST[0]);
}
```

When I use this code, I can see a messagebox with only the first proxy from my list but I would like to load all proxys line by line into a string

Comment: You can use `ReadAllText` method

Comment: To get an array you can use the string split method : string[] Test = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Split(new char[] {'\n'}).ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng ReadAllLines() returns a string[]... why would you want to split the array to convert it to array?

Comment: Because that is what the op asked for.  normally when you parse a text file it is one line at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `File.ReadAllLines` which returns an array of strings, each of which is one line in your file, then you are just getting the first line from that array using `TEST[0]` and displaying it in your message box.

You may want to use `File.ReadAllText` instead to load all your file contents into a single string and then you can simply display it in your message box:

```
string test = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
MessageBox.Show(test);
```

You can get more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads).